# Singular noun in "Each curve and jumping ramp"

Tags: determiners, singular-vs-plural

I came across this sentence in The Wizard of Oz Vocab Builder:

> The water-skier generally maintained an upright position but hunkered down at **each curve** and before **each ramp**.

Why curve and ramp are in their singular forms here? It's more reasonable to encounter many curves and ramps, furthermore, isn't it by using "each", it automatically indicates there are many? Or is it just a typo?

Comment: Yes, **each** is a [determiner](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/English_determiners) that **[occurs only before singular nouns](http://dictionary.cambridge.org/grammar/british-grammar/determiners-and-types-of-noun)**.

Comment: *Each* takes objects one at a time: *Each* time he came to *a* curve or *a* ramp he hunkered down.

Comment: Also, while it doesn't automatically indicate that there are many, it certainly implies that there are.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Each does imply there is more than one, however **each** also signifies they are considered one-by-one, the same as **every**

> at **each** curve and before **each** ramp
>   at **every** curve and before **every** ramp
>   at **each** and **every** curve and before **each** and **every** ramp

all three are equivalent in meaning, though there is greater emphasis in the last one
the plural would be used when referring to curves and ramps collectively:

> at **all** curves and before **all** ramps